# .net Multiple Forms On one page issue

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a view with multiple forms

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Withdrawal", "ATMControl", FormMethod.Post, new {})) 
{
 //code   
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Deposit", "ATMControl", FormMethod.Post, new {})) 
{
//code
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("transfer", "ATMControl", FormMethod.Post, new {})) 
{
//code
}
```

in my controller:

```
//this works
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
                SetViewBagAccounts();
                return View();
        }

//this doesnt

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Withdrawal(ATMModel model)
        {
            //do your login code here
            return View();
        }
```

what i am trying to do is process withdrawal, deposit and transfer indiviually in this controller.
i keep getting this error

The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /ATMControl/Withdrawal

Comment: What is the name of your controller?

Comment: ATMController . I misspelt my controller in view but i made the fix, still same error

Comment: You need to remove the "Controller" part, just use "ATM" when referring to the controller. MVC magic will work it out

Comment: Thanks buddy that was my problem

Comment: Don't forget to accept answers that help you, it will improve your reputation and increase your chances of getting better quality answers in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When referencing a controller by it's name, you should not include the "Controller" part of the name. For example, if your controller class is called `ATMController`, then you should reference it using just `"ATM"`, like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Withdrawal", "ATM", FormMethod.Post, new {})) 
{
}
```

This will translate to the following URL: `/ATM/Withdrawal`

I cannot find a link at the moment to povide you with more information about why this works this way, but you should be aware that the MVC framework will implicitly include the "Controller" part of the name when determining which class is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem using more than a **Html.BeginForm()** in a page.

Your code looks good, so if your controller is named *ATMControlController* you should not get a 404.

Try to use the BeginForm overload without the last argument, that is useless in that case.

Make also sure to build your project. It is a trivial suggestion, but it is a common mistake to save only the View (like in ASP.NET WebForms).

Please post more code for further help.

Comment: in my view i missedspelt my controller. My controller is called ATMController but its still not working, same error

Answer (score 0):

use `/ATM/Withdrawal/` if your controller name is exactly `ATMController`, which mean

```
RouteName + Controller =RouteNameController

then 

/RouteName/ActionName
```